# Spring Boot .JAR doesn't run (maven, intellij, hibernate...)

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

**EDIT**

I have only been working with spring for several weeks now and I can create some basic applications. I'm working on a rest api based app with hibernate connected to mysql using maven build system. I am using IntelliJ Idea for development and making artifacts. I am trying to make single .jar file containing embedded tomcat, which I can deploy just by running that file.

**ISSUE**

In IDE everything runs fine and works properly. When I make executable .jar and try to run it with java -jar, nothing works.

**CODE**

https://github.com/YoungPetr/fitapp

But basically it is just slightly modified https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-mysql-springdatajpa-hibernate

**PROGRESS**

**The first problem:** It says that I am missing embedded servlet container factory bean, which I fix with adding:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory =
            new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    return factory;
}
```

**Then the second issue:** My crud repository interface (autowired as a bean) is not being found and I have to use @EnableJpaRepositories("com.youngpetr.fitapp.server.repositories")

**SUMMARY**

Please note that this whole time the app was runnable in IDE but only .jar had issues.

After fixing the second issue I basically ended up in an infinite loop of missing configurations and when I fix one, another one appears. Missing entity manager bean, missing session factory bean...

Am I missing something in building the project. How is it possible everything is configured fine in IDE and beans are found, jar can't find them.

I have used several tutorials and even tried to run code from them and same issue appears.

my pom.xml looks similar to

```
<!-- GLOBAL PROPERTIES AND SETTINGS -->
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.youngpetr.fitapp.server.Main</start-class>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<!-- BUILD SETTINGS -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<!-- DEPENDENCIES -->
<dependencies>

    <!-- SPRING BOOT -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MYSQL DRIVER -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**SUGGESTION**

When i try another basic tutorial which doesn't use springboot, but just standard spring, with main method that executes and shuts down, everything is fine even with built jar.

I guess there might be problem in the way I am creating .jar and probably in spring boot configuration since in IDE I am getting no errors.

Would switching to .war help me?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What you want to do?? Run your application from the embedded tomcat container which is provided by spring-boot or run it in external tomcat?

Comment: Things started to go wrong when you added the `TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory` bean. I'd take a step back and try to fix that. Sharing all of your code, in a GitHub repo for example, would help a lot as there's lots of stuff missing from your question as it currently stands.

Comment: @RavindraDevadiga I am trying to build a standalone jar with embedded tomcat.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I didn't share that stuff as I am trying to run a basic demo, but I will share it shortly

Comment: As @AndyWilkinson mentioned, things are unclear in your questions. Please share the code in the github

Comment: Ok, put project to github and posted link. Thanks for your patience. But as you can see, the code I posted before was basically everything and it almost the same as tutorial I have posted.

Comment: Once I'd pointed it at an appropriately configured MySQL instance, the project on GitHub works fine for me. It also works fine if a swap out MySQL for an in-memory H2 database. It's going to be very hard to help you if you can't share the code that reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: This is the code i am using. It works fine for me in IDE, but once i make jar artifact and run it in cmd with java -jar, nothing works. That is my issue. Maybe i didn't make myself clear in my post and should rephrase it?

Comment: I have updated the questing, hope it is clearer now

Comment: How are you creating the jar...

Comment: @M.Deinum Yup that was the right direction. I have been creating it by intellij function to create artifacts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after A WHILE of searching among plenty of different issues which were  not applicable, because it seemes my code is all right, I looked into the jar creation process.

I have been creating jar to run by intellij idea function to create artifacts, standard procedure, from module with dependencies, linked main class, added configuration files and all the stuff.

I don't know what is going on there, but when I tried to run everything from the very start manually from the command line (basically just a few maven and java commands), I have managed to create a completely different jar and that one runs properly.

I still have no clue why IDE artifact doesn't work and would appreciate any comments so that people who run into this issue can learn something here.

Big thanks to all guys who gave me a slight hints of where I should and should not look for issues - Ravindra Devadiga, Andy Wilkinson, and even M. Deinum

Comment: The Spring Boot maven plugin generates a special type of artifact. Exporting it using INtellij doesn't invoke that plugin and you are basically creating a corrupted jar (from a Spring Boot point-of-view).

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be driven by maven? And it's dependencies? Any clue why it doesn't invoke that or is it something worth finding some documentation for?

Comment: No it only export a jar maybe with some dependencies. But it doesn't invoke maven for generating it nor honouring that lifecycle.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for an explanation, I will remember that.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your code base and created database with name **fitapp** as you mentioned. One issue I found after that is couldn't create connection to database server.

I found out that version of **mysql-connector-java** which you have mentioned in pom.xml was causing this issue.

Now, I have updated the pom like as shown below(removed the version tag) and it is working fine for me

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Make sure you have update the maven dependencies once you change the pom.xml

Comment: Nothing has changed for me by this, but I have already found a different solution

Comment: what is the solution?